# Sierra: Dock Menu disappears too fast

Tags: dock

On Sierra, I recently noticed that the 'right-click' menu related to Dock applications or Dock Preferences disappears too fast; I am not able to move the mouse fast enough to access any of the menu items before the menu disappears. This seems not affected by toggling the auto-hide feature of the Dock. Anyone else noticed this? Any way to modify the time before menu disappearing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways of navigating menus on macOS:

- Modern: Click or right-click and **release** the button, then click on an option by once again depressing the button and releasing it again.
- Classic: Click or right-click and **keep holding** the button, then move the mouse to the option, where releasing the button on an option selects the option.

It seems like macOS is receiving inputs following half of each of these: the click is held long enough that macOS thinks you're going to use the classic option, but you're actually trying to use modern.

There are a couple of possibilities for why this is occurring:

- There's a bug with the Dock. Restart the Dock with `killall Dock` or log out and back in.
- The mouse is broken and registering a longer click than it should be. Is the button sticking down? Do you have an alternative mouse to try?

Comment: +1. Really well written, detailed and well explained answer.

Comment: Thanks! I had tried 'killall Dock' and logging out with no success. I am having this issue on 2017 Macbook Pro, so I think trackpad was not getting stuck. But doing the 'Classic' method worked and now the 'Modern' method works as well.

Comment: problem seems to have crept back in -- restarting doesn't work; neither does classic or Modern. Any other ideas?